# Limit outputs of neural network between 0 and 1, while also enabling to have exactly 0 and 1

Tags: keras, neural-network, activation-function

My question would be if there is a possibility to limit the outputs of a neural network between 0 and 1, while also enabling it to have exactly 0 and 1 values.

I tried sigmoid activation function in keras, but it enables me to have only ~0.99 and ~0.001, while I would need to be able to predict exactly 1 and 0 too. I also tried linear, but then I will have values which are outside of the interval. Is there any good solution? Could you offer me some help?

Comment: ReLU with max value of 1? Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072838/easy-way-to-clamp-neural-network-outputs-between-0-and-1 hope this answer didn't come too late

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!